# How to pair the two neighbor elements in m*n size matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy

```
for i in range(A):
for j in range(B):
    if j%2==0:
        c=P[i,j]
        d=P[i,j+1]
        Q.append(int(c),int(d))
```

TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given).

Where P is 256*256 matrix.can any one please suggest.
 result should be in this way:Like (1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,) as (10,10,11,10,....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following approach:

```
>>> x = (1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0)
>>> result = []
>>> for i in range(0, len(x), 2):
...     result.append(int(str(x[i])+str(x[i+1])))
... 
>>> result
[10, 10, 11, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

As clearly mentioned, append takes a single value as argument. You're passing in two variables.

The solution for you would be to do:

```
Q.append(int(str(c)+str(d)))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use commas in `c=P[i,j]` you are passing tuples instead of integers as your list indices. The following should work fine for you.

```
for i in range(A):
    for j in range(B):
        if j%2==0:
            c=P[i][j]
            d=P[i][j+1]
            temp = int(str(c) + str(d))
            Q.append(temp)
```

Comment: I got output. Thank you so much for your suggestion, Mr.Utkrah Shekhar.